# Figuring out right value for innodb_buffer_pool_size in MySQL 5.7+

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to understand how can I evaluate any scope of improvement in the value of innodb_buffer_pool_size in MySQL irrespective of the hardware I am using. I am running into two most common approaches suggested in the community:
a. Start with a value >= ~5-10% of the current data + index_data size
b. Set it to ~75-80% of the total available RAM.

I am not sure what should be the basis on which I should decide which of these directions to take ?

I went through the below articles:
[Set to 75% of RAM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19164/what-to-set-innodb-buffer-pool-and-why/19181#19181)
where it says use Query 1 to find the total data size and allot 75% of that size if it exceeds the available RAM size.
On the other hand, [this article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27471/how-much-memory-do-i-need-for-innodb-buffer-pool) says that use Query 2 below to accommodate additional ~5%
growth and assign that value.

How are these values different ? Is it that Query 1 is accounting only for the current data size in the buffer pool and query 2 the size of the entire database(data+index) ?I am also not following what is the '1.1' thing that is being introduced in Query 2.

Query 1:

```
SET @IBPSize = (SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'Innodb_page_size'); -- SELECT @IBPSize;
SET @IBPDataPages = (SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data'); -- SELECT @IBPDataPages;
SET @IBPSize = concat(ROUND(@IBPSize * @IBPDataPages / (1024*1024*1024) * 1.05, 2), ' GB' );
SELECT @IBPSize;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CEILING(RIBPS/POWER(1024,pw)),SUBSTR(' KMGT',pw+1,1))
Recommended_InnoDB_Buffer_Pool_Size FROM
(
    SELECT RIBPS,FLOOR(LOG(RIBPS)/LOG(1024)) pw
    FROM
    (
        SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length)*1.1*growth RIBPS
        FROM information_schema.tables AAA,
        (SELECT 1.05 growth group by growth) BBB
        WHERE ENGINE='InnoDB'
    ) AA
) A;
```

Answer (score 0):

The buffer_pool is being pulled in two directions:

MORE:  The bigger the buffer pool, the more can be cached, hence faster processing.  But if it is so big that it leads to swapping, well, this is *terrible* for performance.  Conclusion:  "More, but not too much".

LESS:  Why waste the RAM if you have only a small dataset?  But the dataset will probably grow, so why bother setting to "small"?  MySQL is not hurt by having the buffer_pool bigger than the dataset, so the `SELECT` is mostly a waste of time.

Let's look at what RAM is needed for:

- The OS
- MySQL code
- Other buffers, caches, etc.
- Other applications running on the same machine.

It's hard to say exactly what those add up to, hence the lack of a precise formula.

So, if you assume there are no other apps on the machine, you can come up with a simple formula.

Plan A:  Assume 1GB for the "other stuff", then give 80% of what's left to the buffer pool.  But this falls apart if you have only 1GB of RAM.

Plan B:  Simply say 70% of RAM.  This works better, but gives too big a number if you have under 4GB of RAM, and too small a number for larger machines.

Plan C:  "75-80%".  This works fine for large machines.

Plan D:  As alluded to, compute the amount of data you have.  But this is only a "lower bound".  But if that leads to swapping, it is bad.  Hence, it is somewhat useless without listing a bunch of caveats.

Note:  All of this discussion applies to all versions that include InnoDB, which goes back as far as 4.0.

Meanwhile, if you *are not* using MyISAM except for system tables set `key_buffer_size = 40M`.  Some space is needed, but not much.

If you are using *both* MyISAM and InnoDB (or just MyISAM), see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory